# How to run my Angular site on mobile device that is running localhost on my windows desktop

Tags: android, networking, localhost, webserver, angular-cli

I know from this question and answer on Super User [Site running on localhost on desktop is unreachable on android device](https://superuser.com/questions/1193168/site-running-on-localhost-on-desktop-is-unreachable-on-android-device/) *(**PS:** this question continues on the question in the link)* that the command `ng serve` opens a bad configured webserver.

The question is how could I run my site on an Android device without deploying my site. I'll try to run the site on this url `http://192.168.0.168:4200` using Angular-CLI.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

try ng serve `--host` option as explained in this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1793  comment by intellix.

1. `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`
2. Find your local IP address by following [this](http://lifehacker.com/5833108/how-to-find-your-local-and-external-ip-address)
3. Navigate to `<local IP adress>:4200` from any device on the same network.

NOTE: If you get CONNECTION_REFUSED just disable your firewall and you should be good to go.

otherwise, try https://ngrok.com/ to open a tunnel from your local network to your computer's localhost. Basically your computer forwards the 4200 port to an external IP and port that any device on the network can access.

Comment: Seems this work instead `ng serve --host=0.0.0.0`

Comment: If the url still isn't available on you mobile device, try to disable a firewall

Comment: Hey this is very cool. But I get this weird behavior that doesn't seem to catch any API responses, is this normal?

Comment: Thank you. It partially worked. But I think it only allows the angular app. through the angular app Backend is not readable. My phone only shows the things which is not connected with the backend. Do I need to up the server with another method? I used "nodemon app.js --host 0.0.0.0". But it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @johnny, your backend would be served from a separate server, which you need to make accessible to the network. I don't know what you use for that ow how you run it. But hopefully it has documentation on how you can do the same thing as angular cli's built-in server.

Comment: `--host 0.0.0.0` was the key for me

Comment: FYI: In order to get the correct Ipv4 address use the cmd 'ipconfig' in the terminal on windows OS, instead of using any online tool/website(i was getting the wrong IP address from online tools)

Comment: In my proxy.conf.json I've added "changeOrigin": true for it to work

Answer (score 45):

1. First verify your machine IP Address.

   - On Windows, type `ipconfig` in Prompt (copy IPv4).
   - On Mac, type `ifconfig |grep inet` in Terminal (copy inet).

   In my case this is `192.168.0.10`.
2. Next, type `ng serve --host 192.168.0.10`.
3. Ok, your app on air for all devices on same network.
4. Now only `http://192.168.0.10:4200/` will work, `localhost` not more.

Comment: how to make mobile nd laptop be on same network??

Comment: i hav connected mobile laptop to same modem thr WIFI but its not loading n mobile

Comment: Using `ipconfig`, I got my real IPv4, when I used online sites to get my IP Address, I've faced this error `An unhandled exception occurred: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available xxx.xxx.xx.xx:4200. See "C:\Users\xx" for further details.`

Comment: @user2900572, connect both devices to the same wifi router. Or turn hotspot on your mobile and connect your laptop to it.

Answer (score 9):

When i tried using

`ng serve --host local_ip_address`

I was facing

> Invalid header Request

This issue was solved using `--disable-host-check`

`ng serve --host local_ip_address --disable-host-check`

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to all the answers above, you might need to adjust your proxy settings on your device. For my Android Phone, this was:

1. Settings
2. Wifi
3. Long Click your desired Network
4. Modify Network
5. Click advanced/extended Options
6. Set `proxyHostname: localhost` and `proxyPort: 4200` and `bypassProxyFor: hostIpAddress`

Answer (score 1):

I open my Angular2 App on Mobile device using [Chrome Remote Device](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/).

You just have to connect your phone to your pc and sync it with chrome.
Than do the port forwarding as described at the link above.

After connect your device, run your Angular app serve with `ng serve --public-host`

Now you can access your app in localhost:4200 from mobile device.

Comment: ng serve --host LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS --disable-host-check

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu people:
get the ip address writing this in the terminal:
`hostname -I`

you will get an ip address something like `192.168.0.0`

and then you can just serve the app with:
`ng serve --host ip_address`

and then you can just open the browser in your mobile with:
`http://ip_address:4200`

Comment: ng serve --host LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS --disable-host-check